# Making HTML accessible in a WebView

Tags: c#, html, webview, uwp, wai-aria

I'm trying to make my HTML code accessible for a screenreaders like JAWS/Narrator.

I tried alot of different things to let JAWS read some text on my HTML page. I managed to get it working by using ARIA like this (the "role" attribute in the div):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head/>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script>...</script>
 </head>
 <body onpaste="return false" oncut="return false">
   <div role="heading">
      <PAGE id="PAGE"></PAGE>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Javascript to add the text:

```
function LoadPage(text)
{
   document.getElementById("PAGE").innerHTML = text;
}
```

The problem is that JAWS reads the text, but it's impossible to navigate trough the words with it. When i press an arrow key, JAWS should tell the next character, but instead, it just repeats the text from the beginning. I know i'm not supposed to add main content text in a heading, but it's the only thing that works. Any suggestions or improvements would be welcome

Comment: First, I suggest changing `<div role="heading">` to just `<heading>`. You may need to make `<PAGE>` an ARIA live region, though if you have very much content that can be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try :)

Comment: It doesn't read anything if i change it to just <heading>

Comment: Making it a `<heading>` alone will not do anything, it just cleans up your code. Without seeing a functional example it is hard to offer advice, but for smaller chunks of content look at [ARIA live regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions). If your `<heading>` only contains a little content, this may work for you. If it contains a lot of content, then a `<heading>` is likely wrong anyway.

Comment: i did something like this :    <PAGE aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions removals" id="PAGE"></PAGE>

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunatly :/

Comment: Then I am probably unable to offer more help. My understanding about the web view is different than how it performs. Good luck.